# Making PC Lint Plus work better with Qt - what options to use (or is there maybe even a .lnt file)?

Tags: c++, qt, pc-lint

I'm trying to coax PC Lint Plus (1.3) to play nice with Qt (5.12) using VisualLint & Visual Studio 2015.

It manages to properly parse things (which is good), but it still generates a lot of noise about some Qt things: For example `#include <QStringList>` points to the `QStringList` file which in turn (only) contains `#include "qstringlist.h"`. It warns that `QStringList` (the file) does have proper include guards, which is technically correct, but as the only content of the file is an `#include` to the correct qt header (which has the required include guards) it is just noise in the end.

Also PC Lint gets rather flustered with Qt's memory management concept (i.e. if you provide a `QObject` with a parent you don't need to `delete` that object, since the parent takes care of deallocation).

So here's the question, has anyone worked with PC Lint Plus on a project that uses Qt, and if so, are there any reccommended options/settings/configurations (or even a .lnt file) to supress the worst of the noise?

Comment: Why do you use PC Lint Plus? I believe something like Clang-Tidy is much more up to date and capable, not to mention free.

Comment: @ruohola I'm not sure if Clang-Tidy has all the features I need - can it do - for example - value tracking? E.g. `x` is initialized as `nullptr` (in one of the possible branches), then `foo(x)` is called, which calls `bar(x)`, which calls `baz(x)`, which finally accesses `x` without doing a `nullptr` check (`foo(x) and `bar(x)` properly check for `nullptr` in their code) - can Clang-Tidy track that and warn me that I`m probably accessing `nullptr` (at least in that one specific path) - PC Lint Plus does provide me with that information/warning...